# Open the door. How to change this into indirect speech?

Tags: sentence-construction, reported-speech

Open the door. 
Can we make its indirect speech?

Example:Open the door. 
He ordered me to open the door. 
He requested me to open the door.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about indirectly quoting someone who said "Open the door", then both of your examples are correct; the second implies that the original speaker was more polite. (You could also say "He requested that I open the door".)

Comment: Sir,  why you put "that"here.

Comment: @user124234: "That" is used to introduce noun clauses.